# Is it possible to loop through properties that have a certain DataAnnotation AND a certain value? .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Let's say i have multiple properties with a Custom DataAnnotation Attribute of:

```
[Objective].
```

I only want to put records in my viewmodel that have the value of 'Y' AND that are decorated with an Attribute of [Objective]

Is this kind of thing possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using reflection. I implemented something similar for [a factory to create dependency properties for WPF](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/10/28/dependency-property-factory-part-3/). Entire source code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/wgFmnUH8).

The relevant piece of code:

```
// Check all properties for a dependency property attribute.
const BindingFlags ALL_PROPERTIES = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var matchingProperties = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, DependencyPropertyAttribute>();
foreach ( PropertyInfo property in m_ownerType.GetProperties( ALL_PROPERTIES ) )
{
    object[] attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( DependencyPropertyAttribute ), false );
    if ( attribute != null && attribute.Length == 1 )
    {
        // A correct attribute was found.
        DependencyPropertyAttribute dependency = (DependencyPropertyAttribute)attribute[ 0 ];

        // Check whether the ID corresponds to the ID required for this factory.
        if (dependency.GetId() is T)
        {
            matchingProperties.Add(property, dependency);
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile I already abstracted this behavior in a hierarchy of abstract classes, because I did something similar when creating [a factory to simplify creating view models](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/viewmodel-property-and-command-factory/), but I believe the above code already answers your question. Source code for this abstract 'factory' can [be found here](http://pastebin.com/5fU6y4z1).

UPDATE:

To access the value of the property, use [PropertyInfo.GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx). You will ofcourse need references to the instances of your class.

Comment: Thanks, it might take me a while to implement this to see if it works, so it might not be accepted til tomorrow :)

Comment: @Doozer1979: I added a abstract class which you can use. It might be missing a few dependencies to my library, but it might get you started.